# How many attempts per second can a password cracker actually make?

Tags: security, passwords

Google searches reveal that password crackers can quickly try millions of combinations and easily crack many passwords.

My research does not show whether they can practically make that many attempts so quickly in a real-world attack.  How do these password-crackers actually have to interface with servers?  Are they filling out the forms in an automated way?  When I submit a password IRL it takes up to several seconds to get a response.  This would multiply the time required for password-cracking by a large factor!  This should provide a lot of protection against these password crackers!

Do password crackers distribute password attempts among many many machines so that they can try them simultaneously?  Isn't this trivial for website servers to recognize as an automated attack?  Is there some faster way that crackers are allowed to make many attempts (and why would servers allow it)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How fast passwords can be cracked varies - by hash type, hardware capability, software used, and number of hashes. There's also an arms race between attackers and defenders that ebbs and flows as time goes on, so the answer to your question will only apply to the rough era that it's asked. So even though another answer was already accepted, and even though the question is probably a duplicate, it's worth re-answering definitively once in a while.

First, it sounds like we need to clarify the difference between **online** and **offline** attacks.

If someone writes software to automate the process of an **online attack** - trying a list of usernames and passwords against an active web interface - they will (hopefully) quickly run into mechanisms designed to stop that (for example, allowing only 5 bad attempts for a given username or from a given IP address in a specific window of time, etc).

By contrast, most password cracking software is designed to perform an **offline attack** - where an attacker has acquired the hashes passwords stored in the back end, and can move them to their own platform to attack in bulk.

So password-cracking discussions are usually centered around about *offline* attacks, because the threat model that matters is if a threat actor *steals your hashes and can attack them using a platform of their choosing*.

Offline cracking speeds are dependent entirely on a variety of factors:

- how well the password was stored (how "slow" the hash is);
- the hardware available to the attacker (usually, more GPUs = better);
- and for well-stored hashes that are "salted", how many hashes are being attacked (fewer unique salts = faster attack, so attacking a single hash would be much faster than attacking a million salted hashes, etc.)

So to put some real numbers to your question:

- One of the most common benchmarks used to compare password-cracking performance is **NTLM** (the hash used by Windows systems to store local passwords). It's useful for benchmarks because it is extremely common, of high interest in many attack models, and also a very "fast" (easier to crack) hash. Recently (February 2019), hashcat demonstrated the ability to crack NTLM hashes on a *single* NVIDIA 2080Ti card at the speed of **[100 billion hashes per second](https://twitter.com/hashcat/status/1095807014079512579)** (disclosure: I'm a member of Team Hashcat). At speeds like that, the vast majority of password-remembering strategies that people use are very likely to be crackable by an attacker with the right tools and know-how. Only the strongest passwords (either random, or random-passphrase based - and of sufficient length/entropy) are entirely out of reach for an attacker.
- By contrast, one of the slowest hashes (and best for the defender) is **bcrypt**. Bcrypt has a 'cost' factor that doubles the cost for the attacker with each iteration. Bcrypt hashes of cost 12 or so are recommended, but even a relatively "fast" bcrypt cost (cost 5), on the same 2080Ti GPU, can only be cracked at a rate of about **28,000 hashes per second**. At that speed, only the weakest passwords can be quickly cracked, middling-strength passwords have "strength in numbers" and are harder to crack in bulk (but can still be cracked if a single person's hash is targeted), and any reasonably strong password will usually be out of reach for the attacker.

Again, these are point-in-time answers, and have to be adapted to your specific threat model.

Also, keep in mind that *password-hash leaks are forever*. Defenders should store passwords today in a way that will be resistant to cracking *for years into the future*, including estimation of future hardware capabilities, Moore's law, etc.

Comment: Your answer has helped me a lot! Could you explain why "attacking a single hash would be much faster than attacking a million salted hashes"?

Comment: Because the unique salt value forces the attacker to separately calculate each candidate password against each hash uniquely.

Answer (score 2):

The [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) is the fastest and most advanced password crack utility. It can run on CPUs and GPUs. It can use multiple cores in the GPU and can be parallelized to use multiple cores and boards. The number of the tested password depends on the applied password protection mechanism. See a benchmark [here](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40). The modern password protection mechanisms as BCrypt and Argon2 has features against fast passwords searches as `memorySizeKB` and `parallelism`.

A System administrator may use the Hashcat to test the passwords of their users. If not easily found, with a threshold with time, then it is a good one. Otherwise, propose the user to change the password. Of course, there should be rules that prevent simple passwords. Min length, numeral, alpha-numerals, etc...

The attackers when they access the system, download the password file then they can use Hashcat. It is not entering a password to login again and again. If so, the login system starts to delay the login mechanism or lock the user account.

The real benefit is that people tend to use the same passwords for other sites, too. Once the attackers find some of the user's passwords from hacked site x then can try another site to see that the password is the same or not.

Comment: What is in the "password file"?  If it contains the passwords, what is left to crack?  Is the attacker then just trying to de-hash?  How would they be able to try many passwords with just this file?

Comment: For others viewing the question, this was a really helpful supplement to the answer from @kelalaka: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U-RbOKanYs&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR0JiaN4dI35oc4HvqWb9OoaGLyZJ3HBWPMtkXqooxjUnZl-R0Zvp1gsUbo

Comment: For example, in Unixes the [/etc/shadow](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/) file contains all the information to crack. The file doesn't contain the passwords, it contains the hashed with high probably salted and pepered. There is no inverse of Cryptographic hash functions, they are one way. The method is public, so you calculated the same method for evey possible combinations to find it.